# simple pivot dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have a simple df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"v": [1, 2]}, index = pd.Index(data = ["a", "b"], name="colname"))
```

Want to reshape it to look like this:

```
  a b
0 1 2
```

How do I do that? I looked at the docs for `pd.pivot` and `pd.pivot_table` but

```
df.reset_index().pivot(columns = "colname", values = "v")
```

produces a df that has NaNs obviously.

**update**: i want dataframes not series because i am going to concatenate a bunch of them together to store results of a computation.

Comment: Seems like you need only the transpose `df.T` ?

Comment: and then just replace the index i guess? i think this is the best solution. happy to accept if you post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your setup

```
        v
colname 
a       1
b       2
```

Seems like you need to transpose

```
>>> df.T
```

or

```
>>> df.transpose()
```

Which yield

```
colname a   b
v       1   2
```

You can always reset the index to get `0` and set the column name to `None` to get your expected output

```
ndf = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
ndf.columns.name = None

    a   b
0   1   2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[out]

```
colname  a  b
0        1  2
```